# knockoutjs strange/(maybe im too dumb to understand) dropdown behaviour

Tags: knockout.js

here's the code i am currently workin on

```
<html>
<head>
@using MvcJqGrid;
@using System.IO;
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@{
    Layout = "";   
    }

<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.base.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/modernizr.custom.05850.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" > </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.19.js"> </script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="Scripts/grid.locale-en.js" ></script>
<script   type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/json2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- This is a *view* - HTML markup that defines the appearance of your UI -->

<p>View Name: <input data-bind="value: sharepointView().Name" /></p>
<p>No Of Results: <input data-bind="value: sharepointView().noOfResultsPerPage"/></p>
<p id='filterEnable' >Filter Expression:Test</p>
<p id='addFilterExpression' >add Filter</p>
<div id='filterExpression'>   
<ul id='filterElements'>
</ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function AppViewModel() {
       //model binding dude
       this.sharepointView=ko.observable(@Html.Raw(PseudoSharepointView.getAView()));

       this.myOptions=(@Html.Raw(PseudoSharepointView.getAllVariables()));
    }

    // Activates knockout.js
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#filterEnable').click(function () {
        $('#addFilterExpression').slideToggle('slow', function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });

    $('#addFilterExpression').click(function () {

  $('#filterElements').append('<li>').append('<p>').html(" 
 <select data-bind='options: $root.myOptions'></select>
          ");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

now the 'select' thingy seems to be givin me a headache

works fine when it is put as is in the body

but when i try to insert the same using a jquery function, i only get an empty dropdown....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript just runs as the page in rendered. Try putting your javascript in a `document.ready` handler and reordering your function calls:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () {
    var viewModel = null;
    function AppViewModel() { 
       //model binding dude 
       this.sharepointView=ko.observable(@Html.Raw(PseudoSharepointView.getAView())); 

       this.myOptions=(@Html.Raw(PseudoSharepointView.getAllVariables())); 
    } 

    $('#filterEnable').click(function () { 
        $('#addFilterExpression').slideToggle('slow', function () { 
            // Animation complete. 
        }); 
    }); 

    $('#addFilterExpression').click(function () { 

       $('#filterElements').append('<li>').append('<p>').html("<select data-bind='options: $root.myOptions'></select>"); 
       ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("filterElements"));
    }); 

    // Activates knockout.js 
    viewModel = new AppViewModel(); 
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});

</script>
```

**Update**: You will also need to call `ko.applyBindings` on any newly created DOM elements that specify a `data-bind` attribute. See above in the `$('#addFilterExpression').click` function

Comment: didnt work..... the problem i am actually facing is as follows...
   
 <select data-bind='options: myOptions'></select> 
 works fine when i use it within the markup and the dropdown is populated as intended....

but...when i try to  do the same thing using a jquery click function


$('#addFilterExpression').click(function () {



     $('#filterElements').append('<li>').append('<p>').html(" <select data-bind='options: myOptions'></select>  "); 



        
   
    });

all i get is an empty dropdown

Comment: Ah! The problem is that the DOM element has not been created when you do your ko.applyBindings. Therefore, you need to tell knockout to apply the bindings again in your addFilterExpression click handler. I have updated by answer accordingly.